# Typescript 2.4 causes compilation errors in simple generics use cases

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript2.4

I've been trying to upgrade a project from TypeScript 2.3 to 2.4 but it's proving rather frustrating and confusing. I'm getting some errors related to generics that I can't understand.

I've broken out a section of code and simplified it as much as possible:

```
interface Service  {
    serviceName: string;
}

interface TableParams {
    selectionListLabelFn: <T>(item: T) => string;
}

const tableParams: TableParams = {
    selectionListLabelFn: (service: Service) => service.serviceName
};
```

The code above generates the following error:

```
λ tsc test.ts
test.ts(9,7): error TS2322: Type '{ selectionListLabelFn: (service: Service) => string; }' is not assignable to type 'TableParams'.
  Types of property 'selectionListLabelFn' are incompatible.
    Type '(service: Service) => string' is not assignable to type '<T>(item: T) => string'.
      Types of parameters 'service' and 'item' are incompatible.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Service'.
```

Why is this happening? It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the error is not a mistake. The reason is that `selectionListLabelFn` is declared as a generic delegate, so a generic delegate should be passed in not one that has a `Service` parameter. You can create a generic arrow function like this:

```
const tableParams: TableParams = {
    selectionListLabelFn: <T>(service: T) => ""
};
```

If you want `selectionListLabelFn` to be tied to `Service`, you can try declaring it on the interface :

```
interface TableParams<T> {
    selectionListLabelFn: (item: T) => string;
}    
const tableParams: TableParams<Service> = {
    selectionListLabelFn: (service: Service) => service.serviceName
};
```

The rules might have more strict between versions, but in I am not necessarily surprised by the error. I think I might be related to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16368) item that was included in 2.4

Comment: I can't specify the entire interface as generic (well, I can, but it wouldn't make sense). The type is quite a bit larger than what it shown in the example. What I'm trying to achieve is to define a generic function that I can provide multiple implementations of that work with any number of data types. Another example could be this: `selectionListLabelFn: (c: Country) => c.name || c.id`

Comment: But do you expect that for the same instance of `TableParams` `selectionListLabelFn` will be called with different `T`s ?

Comment: No. One instance takes one type only.

Comment: Then I believe adding the generic type to your interface is the best course. If you type a variable to just `TableProps` then the compiler cannot check that you are passing the required type to the function. If you type it with the generic parameter then you ensure callers cannot pass the wrong parameter to the function.

Comment: In 2.3 the following code would compile, but it would generate a runtime error:
`const tableParams: TableParams = {
    selectionListLabelFn: (service: Service) => service.name
};

tableParams.selectionListLabelFn({});` This is why they changes it, because the compiler did not catch such errors.